# How to save a field value according to another field value and with a user presave hook

Tags: 8

I'm using Drupal 8

There are field_a and field_b. I'd like to field_b have the same value with field_a but different format after user submit his user edit page.

```
my_module_user_presave($account)

{
 $data = $account->field_a->value; // There is no value, since this user did not save yet. This is the problem.
 $account->field_b->value=format($account->field_a);//format function will change the format of field_a value, and this is not a problem
}
```

Since the user did not save yet, so there is no value for field_a. So I am trying to use drupal_register_shutdown_function as below.

```
my_module_user_presave($account)

{
 drupal_register_shutdown_function('_my_module_user_presave',$account);
}
_my_module_user_presave($account)

{
 $data = $account->field_a->value;
 $account->field_b->value=format($account->field_a); //format will change the format of field_a value.
}
```

Now the field_a got the value. But field_b value will not be saved since drupal_register_shutdown_function.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: The first version of the presave hook should work. You can access the field values before the user is saved. What field type is field_a?

Comment: "Since the user did not save yet, so there is no value for field_a". This makes no sense to me, why wouldn't it? in case of user, even the ID is available then.

Comment: Hey @4k4 and Berdir. Thanks for your reply, guys! 4k4, text field for both of field_a and field_b. I'm pretty sure it does not work. Trust me I have tried a lot of time. It only can access the old value. For example, the old value of field_a is 2016, I'm trying to change it to 2017 and after I tap save, the field_b will get the 2016 (old value) rather than 2017 (new value). It does make sense. The value will be saved after presave executing over, but field_b tried to access the value when presave executing, so it gets the old value for sure (the new value not save yet).

Comment: @Berdir please see the above

Comment: No, that makes no sense. The entity in presave is what is being saved, not the old values. The hook is "Thing is the thing I am saving now, do you want to change something". What @4k4 wrote should definitely work and I've done things like that many times.

Comment: Sorry guys, I made a mistake and you guys are totally right! The value did not save because function. I have fixed it. Thanks for help a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change a field according to another field:

```
function mymodule_user_presave($account) {

 $data = $account->field_a->value;
 $account->field_b->value = strtoupper($data);

 drupal_set_message($account->original->field_a->value . ' > ' . $account->field_a->value);
 drupal_set_message($account->original->field_b->value . ' > ' . $account->field_b->value);

}
```

To get the original values you would have to use $account->original. Otherwise you get the new values. To prove that it's working this is the output in messages from the code above after I entered `abcdef` in field_a:

> abc > abcdef
>
> ABC > ABCDEF
>
> The changes have been saved.

Comment: Sorry @4k4 I made a mistake and you guys were totally right, I was wrong! The value did not save because a function in my code. I have fixed it. Thanks for help a lot!